# How do I set max_allowed_packet or equivalent for MySQLdb in python?

Tags: python, mysql

It seems as if MySQLdb is restricting the maximum transfer size for SQL statements. I have set the `max_allowed_packet` to `128M` for `mysqld`. MySQL documentation says that this needs to be done for the client as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `max_allowed_packet` into the `[client]` section of `my.cnf` on the machine where the client runs. If you want to, you can specify a different file or group in `mysqldb.connect`.